# how to use repeater data inside style tag in asp

Tags: coding-style, tags, repeater

I am using repeater control to get average rating from database and I want to use that average rating inside style tag for width..

I am using the code as:
style="height:15px; width:'" & <%# Eval(Container,"DataItem.AverageRating")"' %>"
but it is giving an error "tag not well formed"
please tell..

Answer (score 2):

you can use this its worked for me

```
style='<%#"height:15px; width:" + Eval(Container,"DataItem.AverageRating").ToString() +"px;"'
```

Answer (score 0):

one way is you can make a method in your code-behind that will return a string
e.g

```
<input <%# WriteWidth( Eval(Container,"DataItem.AverageRating").ToString() ) %>
```

then in the code-behind:

```
protected string WriteWidth(string Width)
{
 return string.format(" style='height: 15px, width: {0}px'", Width);
}
```